# Excel 2013 creating external links when copying over worksheet to another workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have some workbooks that on excel 2007 when i copy it over to a workbook, i do not get the annoying prompt to update external links. Since i have updated to 2013, I've been getting the prompt to update external links which I cannot find out where in my macros or cells are there anything referencing back to the original copy that i copied over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bill Manville has a tool called FindLink, available [here](http://www.manville.org.uk/software/findlink.htm) for free. This can find links in formulas, named ranges, conditional formatting, chart series, etc.